# Show one result each ID and keep time order

Tags: mysql, sql

I've created the following query which works with a slight problem:

```
SELECT pe.*, cache.column1,p.column2,p.ID
  FROM events AS pe
  INNER JOIN cache ON pe.ID = cache.ID
  INNER JOIN places AS p ON pe.ID = p.ID
WHERE pe.createdTime > *NOW UNIX TIME*
  GROUP BY pe.ID
  ORDER BY pe.createdTime ASC LIMIT 6
```

It shows the latest records as excepted, unless there are multiple records of **pe** table of the same **p.ID**, it shows the farthest **pe** table record (farthest = **latest pe.createdTime** instead of the upcoming).

Tried some changes, it's still shows the farthest record of this place( **p.ID**). Looking for your help!

Comment: consider providing proper DDLs (and/or sqlfiddle) and a desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to fetch the record with the latest pe time.  You can do this with aggregation and a join:

```
SELECT pe.*, c.column1, p.column2,p.ID
FROM events pe INNER JOIN
     cache c
     ON pe.ID = c.ID INNER JOIN
     places p ON pe.ID = p.ID INNER JOIN
     (SELECT pe.id, MIN(createdTime) as minct
      FROM events pe
      WHERE pe.createdTime > *NOW UNIX TIME*
      GROUP BY pe.id
     ) pemin
     ON pe.id = pemin.id and pe.createdTime = pemin.mminct
GROUP BY pe.ID
ORDER BY pe.createdTime ASC
LIMIT 6;
```

You probably don't need the `group by` but without knowing your data, that is hard to say for sure.

Comment: Thank you sir! I've learned the idea of the query you provided and changed it to my needs to solve my solution. It works great - and I actually needed MIN value instead of MAX.